# How does MSBuild EmbedInteropTypes work with PIAs and COMReferences?

Tags: .net, msbuild

I am rationalizing the proj files for a large system that includes usages of MS Office (Excel) interop. I have found so far two different types of references:

1. "Reference" tag with "EmbedIntopTypes" set to true. The include value is a strong name for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
2. "COMReference" tag with "EmbedInteropTypes" set to true, plus tags for Guid, VersionMajor, VersionMinor, Lcid, and WrapperTool.

The reading I've done leads me to believe that #1 is referencing a PIA (we are currently targeting Office 2010, after which I've read that MS doesn't ship PIAs due to addition of the "EmbedInteropTypes" feature).

#2 appears to be a COM reference that would result in creation of a PIA (via the WrapperTool tag) at build time.

It seems to me that EmbedInteropTypes can't replace PIAs (at least on the dev/build machines) because it actually *uses* the PIAs, so I don't really understand the notion that MS has stopped shipping PIAs in favor of EmbedInterop types.

I cannot seem to find any definitive documentation on MSDN that actually explains how COM references are intended to be accomplished at the present time (actually as of VS2010/.NET 4.0, although I haven't yet read anything referencing features added after .NET 4.0).

So my question is: how are references to COM objects (such as MS Office Excel, but a generally applicable answer would be best) intended to be coded in MSBuild files (csproj/vbproj/etc.) today? Ideally there would be an approach that makes it easy to handle multiple versions, and also to avoid requiring the COM objects be fully installed/registered on the build machine (e.g. to avoid potential additional license costs).